# Do the validation policies still apply to us if we use a 3rd party payment model?

Tags: office-js, office-store

The query related to the link for the Office Web App Validation policies version 1.9.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj220035(v=office.15)#bk_7

The query is regarding Section# 7.17 (7.16.1, 7.16.2, 7.16.3):
They are planning for an office app in which they want to use a third party payment system which is a subscription based model. Let say their application supports 5 different features which are available to user via different subscriptions like –

FREE subscription: Free plan having only 3 features.
PAID BASIC subscription: Paid plan having only 4 features.
PAID PREMIUM subscription: Paid plan having all the 5 features.

My queries-
1.       So in that case the Section# 7.17 (7.16.1, 7.16.2 and 7.16.3) are applicable or not? Which mean I have to host a three different applications on office store under the name MyApp_Free, MyApp_Basic, MyApp_Preminium. Please mind that my payment model is a third party.
2.       Or I can host a single app which comprise of all the above mention subscription.

What I have understood so far from these Validation policies Section# 7.17 (7.16.1, 7.16.2 and 7.16.3) that they are applicable to the application which have used the Office store payment model, since we can’t have different set of features/ subscription under one payment method, we are using 3rd party, will the below points still apply to someone who is using a 3rd party payment model?

Comment: These are more business questions than programming questions and off topic for SO - you might have some luck on the Microsoft forum here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?forum=appsforoffice

Answer (score 0):

7.17 does not apply to you if you want to ship a single app to the Store with 3rd-party payment options. You're welcome to ship one app that uses your own custom subscription/payment model.

-Michael (PM for Office add-ins)